# symfony2 - default value for "entity" field?

Tags: symfony, entity

i am creating a form field ,this is correct in my project .

```
enter code here
role:
    type: entity
    attributs:
        class: 'SystemUserBundle:Group'
        property: name   
        expanded: false
        multiple: true
```

how add default value to this handle?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your `data` having a default value:

```
// User::getRole() = function { return new Role('DEFAULT'); }
$object = new User;
$form->setData($object);
```

Comment: data  Group in another database is json

Comment: it doesn't change the fact that default value should come from data object. How you get it is a totally different problem.